# How to swap entire html blocks in multiple files with sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk, find

I have tons of html pages with a simlar content as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="aaa">
...lot of html1 here like div's/spans etc..
</div> <!-- end aaa -->

<div class="bbb">
...lot of html2 here
</div><!-- end bbb -->

</div>
```

I need to swap div's with aaa and bbb classes entirely with their content:

So it becomes:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="bbb">
...lot of html2 here
</div><!-- end bbb -->

<div class="aaa">
...lot of html1 here
</div> <!-- end aaa -->

</div>
```

NOTES:

1) Empty lines between the blocks are optional. 
2) HTMLs contain only one exact pair of `aaa` and `bbb`
so, the case: `aaa` then `bbb` then `aaa` is not possible.

So could you please advise what arguments should I pass to `sed`. I'm using `find` to find all html files and then launch `sed` as exec param:

```
find . -iname "*.html" -exec sed -i '' 's/WHAT IS HERE / AND HERE /g' {} \;
```

If it is not possible with `sed` but let's say is possible, with `awk` I will be glad if you could share your thoughts on the best way to achieve the desired.

UPDATE:

Here is the link to real life example: 
http://pastebin.com/mdhJ9rtL

Comment: Please take a look closely. Example is already added :)

Comment: @Sigur, yup, exactly.

Comment: Is aaa and bbb meets in htmls together? Many times or just one?

Comment: Do you know that there are blank lines in between?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put `aaa` section from before `bbb` just after it:

```
sed -i '/<div class="aaa">/{
        :1
        /<\/div> <\!-- end aaa -->/!{N;b 1}
        /<\/div> <\!-- end aaa -->/{N;h}
        d}
        /<\/div><\!-- end bbb -->/{n;G}' *html
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you code returns "extra characters at the end of p command". Could you please advise?

Comment: @Sray Is there some metacharacters in your classes content - especially `/` (because there is no `p` command in the script)? You can try to change each `/` in script to other some symbol which surely do not present in your content. For example `\|<div class="aaa">| { ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is not work for `sed`, unless you are a glutton for punishment. At least in a more general case, where the beginning of the block is more then one line (or whee the tags are split across several lines, which is well possible in XML/HTML).

If you really must do this with anything else than an XML parser (yes, either fixing the input or cutting out the broken parts would generally be a better idea), use something like `awk` at least - it's much more suitable for a task like that<sup>*)</sup>. General idea is to:

1. print input lines until the beginning of the first block;
2. accumulate lines of the first block to swap;
3. accumulate lines between the blocks;
4. print lines of the second block;
5. print lines of the part between the blocks accumulated in step 3;
6. print lines of the first block accumulated in step 2;
7. print the rest.

Also remember to check the [canonical SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

<sup>*</sup> Why I claim that: sed is line-oriented and intended for simple ([your mileage may vary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#cite_note-gamez-6)) text transformations. While this holds true for AWK (and in some degree for Perl) as well, writing more complex scripts is simpler in the latter (easier access to multiple variables, automatic splitting into fields etc.). Thus unless you only need to swap two extremely well delimited blocks and will never need to extend the script to handle differently formatted input, a more complex language will likely be a better tool. That said, Perl has a XML parser readily available as a module.

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk. I will be grateful if you could provide me with example.

Comment: How is `awk` *more suitable*? That is an unfounded assertion. People often say things like that but I think it is because they just know how to use one better than the other - which may speak to their preference, but not the capability of the tool. This is very easily done with `sed` by the way.

Comment: @mikeserv more suitable in general case - try matching three following lines as a beginning of block. It might be easy in *this particular case* but if it gets a bit more complicated `sed` is not the way to go. (And neither is `awk`, but that's only repeating the answer.)

Comment: Also try to use `sed` in case there is something between the two blocks. You can do it (`sed` is Turing complete), but it will stop being comprehensible to most people.

Comment: No, these things are simple with `sed` - and they always are - `sed` is *extremely simple*. `sed` is very *simple* - if most people don't understand how it works, it is because most people make little effort to understand data flow, and require instead that a computer needlessly buffer to better accommodate their level of understanding. I will post an answer that demonstrates this with `sed` - though there is an excellent one here already, perhaps I can show another way - as there are several. Just a few minutess

Comment: @mikeserv and you have nicely proven my points with your answer. The notation, however effective it might be, is not of the most readable ones (although that can be helped a bit by indentation (and comments). Second, try adding one more `<div>` inside of, say, block a. That is the breakage caused by sed not being a XML parser. AWK would break in the same way, but I still maintain that extending script logic would be easier in AWK than in sed (again: both are Turing complete, so one can implement at least a restricted XML parser, but nobody wants to).

Comment: No, that is a problem with the code I wrote - this is not designed to parse arrays - that's a more difficult thing to do. This is designed to strip `<div.../div>` blocks from a `<div wrapper>`. I could do that thing you say - but it would be harder to do. Maybe 15 lines, as opposed to the four. Also, I find `/<.div>/!N;/<!-- end/x;/<.div>/x;//!bn` to be very readable. It is exactly what it looks like: *if not div next line, if end exchange, if div exchange, if not still div branch to next label* - it's just abbreviated. But that's why the single letter commands are important - they stand out.

Comment: I certainly didn't prove any of your points. You can easily see it is easily done, yes? In any case, among us two, I am not the only one that isn't proving your point, by the way.

Comment: And by the way, I am not a little underwhelmed to find you raising the bar after the fact. You said: *Also try to use sed in case there is something between the two blocks.* And so I did - easily, and efficiently - and then some - but it must now also recursively delimit delimiters? That is pretty silly. You should face it - maybe you have a preference for `awk` for whatever reason - but for a task like this, it no more capable than is `sed`. In my experience the tool matters much less than does the craftsman,

Comment: @mikeserv Please do 1) re-read the original question: `<div>...lot of html1 here</div>` - you can easily expect another `<div>` to be contained therein; 2) re-read my reply to your original comment: *"[sed] might be easier in this particular case, but if it gets a bit more complicated..."*; 3) consider that the wording you are using might be considered quite confrontational at best. As for the points proven, I'm leaving it to the readers of this discussion. We might as well be interpreting each other slightly differently, who knows.

Comment: My replies are to a confrontational answer *(which is not an answer, actually)*. Yes, I see *lot of html here* - there are *MANY* tags that are not *<div>*. Here, we have a `<div class="wrapper">` and so my answer swaps - *(one deep)* - blocks within. Again your point is that *`awk` is more suitable for a task like that* - which is completely unfounded, and contrary to the evidence *as there are two `sed` answers here, and 0 `awk` ones*. *My point* is that the language is unimportant, but it is the coder that matters. And it is also that you make unfounded claims.

Comment: Peter, @mikeserv please don't have long conversations like this in the comments. That's what chat is for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `sed`:

```
sed '/.*<div class="...">.*/{ h;s///;x;:n
     /<.div>/!N;/<!-- end/x;/<.div>/x;//!bn
    s/\(.*\).\(<div class=.*>\).*/\2\1/;x
     /<.div>[^>]*$/s/.//;H;x
}'
```

Starting from a `class=.???.` line and running through however many blocks you have, for each pair this swaps their positions. So, here are some examples:

If `sed` encounters a line that matches:

```
<div class=".\{3\}">
```

...while reading its in file it will ensure `H`old space is completely clear and then begin pulling in every line until it encounters either a line that matches:

```
<.div>
```

...*and*...

```
<!-- end
```

...or just the former. If it matches both then `sed` saves the block in an alternate buffer and pulls in a second block before swapping their positions on output.

If just the former it does not affect the blocks position. In this way misatched pairs are left alone.

Given as input...

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="aaa"> first </div> <!-- end aaa -->
between
<div class="bbb"> swap two </div> <!-- end bbb -->
blocks
<div class="ccc"> mismatched </div> <!-- end ccc --> 
the end         
</div>
```

It prints...

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bbb"> swap two </div> <!-- end bbb -->
between
<div class="aaa"> first </div> <!-- end aaa -->
blocks
<div class="ccc"> mismatched </div> <!-- end ccc -->
the end
</div>
```

...if given:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="aaa"> first </div> <!-- end aaa -->
between
<div class="bbb"> swap two </div> <!-- end bbb -->
blocks
<div class="ccc"> matched </div> <!-- end ccc --> 
the end
<div class="ddd"> now matched </div> <!-- end ddd -->
</div>
```

It prints...

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bbb"> swap two </div> <!-- end bbb -->
between
<div class="aaa"> first </div> <!-- end aaa -->
blocks
<div class="ddd"> now matched </div> <!-- end ddd -->
the end
<div class="ccc"> matched </div> <!-- end ccc -->
</div>
```

And, though the examples are all crunched up like that for space's sake, it has no real concern for whether or not the `<div class=` begin and the `<.div> <!-- end` sections fall on the same line or not:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="aaa">

the first
block is here

</div> <!-- end aaa -->

these lines were
between aaa and bbb

<div class="bbb">

this is the second block
it should be swapped with the first

</div> <!-- end bbb -->

more
blocks
follow

<div class="ccc"> this is matched </div> <!-- end ccc -->
not the end
<div class="ddd">

this last block
is matched with the ccc line
</div> <!-- end ddd -->

this is the end
</div>
```

Gets...

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bbb"> 

this is the second block
it should be swapped with the first

</div> <!-- end bbb -->

these lines were
between aaa and bbb

<div class="aaa"> 

the first
block is here

</div> <!-- end aaa -->

more
blocks
follow

<div class="ddd"> 

this last block
is matched with the ccc line
</div> <!-- end ddd -->
not the end
<div class="ccc"> this is matched </div> <!-- end ccc -->

this is the end
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This works if blocks contain only texts. But in case they contain other divs, this script just pulls out one of the children divs before the parent instead of changing the places of two parent divs.

Comment: @Sray - this won't do nested instances. In fact - such a thing is not possible with regular expressions because language with contextual grammar ceases to be regular. You can recurse the parse though - you just have stack each level.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not stand out. But this script just takes a child <div> let's say with class ccc and places it before div with class aaa. So it becomes: `<div class="ccc">some content</div><div class="aaa"></div><div class="bbb"></div>` Instead of `<div class="bbb"></div><div class="aaa"><div class="ccc"></div></div>` I don't need to process internal content, just swap aaa and bbb without touching the children divs/spans etc..

Comment: @Sray - and how are these delimited? The same way as the internal content? There's no clear cut way for skipping over the internals without a top-level delimiter.

Comment: No, ccc is the internal content of aaa. It should stayed untouched. Just swap aaa and bbb. Please take a look at the real life example: http://pastebin.com/mdhJ9rtL

Comment: @Sray - so all you want to move are the declaration lines? That's doable - so long as every end line has that comment matching its name; I guess. You might want to ask another question and state that part clearly. When I get to a computer if I see it maybe I'll take a whack at it.

Comment: Not the declaration lines, but blocks entirely, with entire content. When you have some time, I would be glad if you could look a little bit closer at the output of your command and expected results (link above). I guess it is necessary to modify your script a little bit, but unfortunately, I'm not quite strong with sed.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regex is clearly discouraged.

Instead, you can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) & [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) if your source files are valid XHTML :

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "//div[@class='a']" -v 'some inner HTML' file.xhtml
```

If it's not valid XHTML, try to adapt the following perl code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.008;

use File::Slurp 'read_file';
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

sub replace_keyword
{
  my $elt = shift;

  return if $elt->is_empty;

  $elt->normalize_content;      # Make sure text is contiguous

  my $content = $elt->content_array_ref;

  for (my $i = 0; $i < @$content; ++$i) {
    if (ref $content->[$i]) {
      # It's a child element, process it recursively:
      replace_keyword($content->[$i])
          unless $content->[$i]->tag eq 'a'; # Don't descend into <a>
    } else {
      # It's text:
      if ($content->[$i] =~ /here/) { # your keyword or regexp here
        $elt->splice_content(
          $i, 1, # Replace this text element with...
          substr($content->[$i], 0, $-[0]), # the pre-match text
          # A hyperlink with the keyword itself:
          [ a => { href => 'http://example.com' },
            substr($content->[$i], $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]) ],
          substr($content->[$i], $+[0])   # the post-match text
        );
      } # end if text contains keyword
    } # end else text
  } # end for $i in content index
} # end replace_keyword


my $content = read_file('foo.shtml');

# Wrap the SHTML fragment so the comments don't move:
my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$html->store_comments(1);
$html->parse("<html><body>$content</body></html>");

my $body = $html->look_down(qw(_tag body));
replace_keyword($body);

# Now strip the wrapper to get the SHTML fragment back:
$content = $body->as_HTML;
$content =~ s!^<body>\n?!!;
$content =~ s!</body>\s*\z!!;
```

Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900870/how-can-i-modify-html-files-in-perl

Comment: It's not valid XHTML. Moreover, the inner content of both 'aaa' and 'bbb' div's is quite a big chunk of code.

Comment: The inner content should not be a very big deal, but malformed HTML is.

Comment: OK, could you please explain how it works? Honestly, never heard about this command.